# Calling both weak and strong function symbol?

Tags: c++, linux, linker, shared-libraries

I have a library that provides a function func():

```
return_type func(type arg);
```

It was necessary to override it by my own implementation in my application. It was possible because the library provides a weak symbol func while the func symbol in my application is a strong one. (That is my understanding.)

Now I want to be able to call both implementations of func - library's implementatoin and my own implementation:

```
// The problem is that the names are the same.
func(); // Everything is OK, calling my implementation (in my application)
func(); // How can I call library's implementation now?
```

I can call my implementation because it overrides the implementation in the library. But how can I call the implementation in the library? How can I refer to it?

Comment: you should look into the `-wrap` option of GNU ld to see if it can help you

Answer (score 1):

If the functions are in shared libraries, you can load them with `dlopen` and the obtain the symbols from `dlsym`. You can then have different function pointers for for the functions from each library.

If the functions are in a static library, you will need to modify the static library to change the name. This can be done with something like `objcopy --prefix-symbols=foo_ foo.o`. Not sure if this can be done directly on a `.a` in such a case, you might need to expand the archive.

Having added the prefix you will then need to modify any header files to take the new names either using a macro or something similar.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have a library and an  application that uses that library. and I can't modify the library. I've overridden the library's func with my own func (from the application). But I need to call the library's implementation also.

Comment: Is it a static or shared library?

Comment: The library comes in both variants - static and shared. So I need a solution that works for both static and shared libraries.